# Is it safe to connect a power strip to UPS?

Tags: power, raspberry-pi, ups

I need to run a PC and multiple raspberry pis (8 nodes cluster) non-stop 24/7. And my UPS machine has only 3 sockets.

Connect a [ups](http://powerful.com.tr/urun/pl-1500-1500va/) to [power strip](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRX6J6SMltJS6Rx8sPwWW5nIObde99YeqUVKyYkn8UZOpV73f4M&usqp=CAU) is wrong according to this site: https://www.apc.com/mk/en/faqs/FA158852/

Ok, a UPS should connect to directly into the wall receptacle. But what about, connect a power strip to UPS?
Is it safe? Can I connect my raspberry pis to a power strip and then a UPS?
(One ups socket for PC, other UPS socket for raspberry pi's power strip.)

Comment: Sure. Why not? As long as you’re not over the rating of anything.

Answer (score 1):

It says to not use a "surge protector" power strip, if you avoid those, then you will be fine, providing your within the load limits of the UPS